# How to compare pronouncation accuracy of a recoreded voice with an audio file already on device and return similarity percentage in android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mfcc, dtw

I'm trying to make an app that check accuracy percentage of pronunciation of users with an already recorded audio file , I have read about the subject and I got that the best way is to convert both audio files into MFCCs and then compare them using dynamic time warping (DTW) algorithm, but the results I get are always between 70 and 90 percent even if I recorded different sentences from the ones in the audio file in device, I've tried CosineDistance & EuclideanDistance algorithms, I also tried to normalize values for the MFCCs, but got nothing, still getting the same problem.

this is the class I use to check similarity percentage

```
class SimilarityChecker {
    private val sampleRate = 16000
    private val nMFCC = 13
    private val bufferSize = 512
    private val nFFT = 2048
    private val hopLength = 512
    private val nMels = 128

    fun percentage(file1Path: String, file2Path: String): Double
    {
        val mfcc1 = extractMFCCs(file1Path)
        val mfcc2 = extractMFCCs(file2Path)
        

        val percentage = calculateDTWDistance(mfcc1 , mfcc2)

        return (percentage * 100.0).roundToInt() / 100.0
    }


    private fun extractMFCCs(@NonNull path: String): MutableList<MutableList<Float>> {
        Log.i("path from Main:", path)
        var fileList = JLibrosa().loadAndRead(path, sampleRate, -1)

        val MFCC = JLibrosa().generateMFCCFeatures(fileList, sampleRate, this.nMFCC, nFFT, nMels, hopLength)
            .map { arr -> arr.toList() }


        return MFCC.map { d -> d.toMutableList() }.toMutableList()
    }


    private fun calculateDTWDistance(
        referenceFeatures: MutableList<MutableList<Float>>,
        studentFeatures: MutableList<MutableList<Float>>
    ) : Double {
        val dtw = DTW()
        val ldTW = io.github.cawfree.dtw.DTW()

        var distances: MutableList<Double> = mutableListOf()
        for (i in referenceFeatures.indices) {
            distances.add(
                FastDTW.compare(
                    TimeSeriesBase(
                        referenceFeatures[i].mapIndexed { index, value ->
                            TimeSeriesItem(
                                index.toDouble(),
                                TimeSeriesPoint(doubleArrayOf(value.toDouble()))
                            )
                        }
                    ),
                    TimeSeriesBase(
                        studentFeatures[i].mapIndexed { index, value ->
                            TimeSeriesItem(
                                index.toDouble(),
                                TimeSeriesPoint(doubleArrayOf(value.toDouble()))
                            )
                        }
                    ),
                    10, Distances.EUCLIDEAN_DISTANCE
                ).distance
            )

        }

        val distance = distances.average()


        return if (distances.max() == 0.0) 100.0 else ((distances.max() - distance) / distances.max()) * 100
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Just making sure you are aware of: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=voice+similarity

Comment: Yes, implemented some of the suggestions .. but i still get wrong results.

Comment: Check this app: https://www.codester.com/items/25375/english-pronunciation-android-app-template